# How to remove/disable the "Suspend" button in Ubuntu console?

Tags: 14.04

The little "power" icon in the upper right screen has a "Suspend" function "(along with Logout, Shutdown, etc.) I would like to either remove "Suspend" or make it do nothing or take some other action instead of suspend. How do I edit this particular menu entry?

Comment: here info for 16.04 https://askubuntu.com/a/939101/37213