# How to remove the suspend and lock button from menu in ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: suspend

I am trying to restrict the users from accessing suspend and lock button in the menu. I have used dconf editor to restrict access to shutdown menu but cant find a way to restrict suspend option.

Any help?

Answer (score 10):

Found solution from [Explanation of file - org.freedesktop.login1.policy - 
 Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289123/explanation-of-file-org-freedesktop-login1-policy)

Open file explorer with `sudo` privileges.

```
sudo -H nautilus
```

Browse to `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.login1.policy`. Make a copy of the file for restore purposes and search for each of the following.

```
org.freedesktop.login1.suspend
org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions       org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-ignore-inhibit       org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
```

For each of the above action id scroll down past the translations to change the following from yes to no

```
<defaults>
     <allow_any>no</allow_any>
     <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
     <allow_active>no</allow_active>
</defaults>
```

Save and reboot.

Comment: Hi MZF, will this be overwritten by certain system updates?

Comment: @TiloBunt as far as I know: no.

Comment: This worked great to remove the suspend menu item under 16.04.5. I only modified `org.freedesktop.login1.suspend` and `org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions`

Comment: (Ubuntu 20.04) Worked immediately after changing the file. Doesn't need a restart.